# Iptables and system-config-firewall

Tags: iptables

I had a set of netfilter rules set with `iptables`, but someone else told me to use `system-config-firewall` to add a rule for sharing files with Windows. (Samba) This rewrote the iptables rules file and I lost my own custom rules.

I have a backup copy, but am having trouble restoring them.

**Edit:** The server is Centos, I already tried to restore the rules with 
`iptables-restore < /root/working.iptables.rules` but for some reason the rules don't change.

**What are you trying to do?**
Trying to restore the iptable rules that I have in a backup file.

**What have you tried in order to make it happen?**
I've tried to modify the iptables file with `vim`, since the command `iptables-restore` was no help.

**What results did you expect?**
To get the old rules back.

**What actually happened?**
Nothing, when I run the command or edit the file by hand the file doesn't change at all. Maybe something else it's overwriting.

Comment: what OS are you using (e.g. redhat), what other steps did you take (e.g. iptables restart)...

Comment: This question does not meet Server Fault's quality standards. You are providing *no* useful detail or troubleshooting information. Please take a look at [this Meta topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) for some tips on improving your question so it can be reopened.

Comment: Now it's good enough?

Comment: Maybe the format of your iptables backup isn't what `iptables-restore` expects. Instead, you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and then restart the service.

Comment: thx Aaron I will check it right now!